# How to mark noisy points on from a signal

Tags: matlab

I have a signal like this

[image: plot 1]

And now i need to mark the points that are considered noisy in the signal. How to do that?

Noisy parts are just as shown in the zoomed in version of the plot and how to mark the noisy points in this signal by using matlab?

[image: plot 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code might work:

```
array=abs([0 diff(signal)])
threshold_for_noisy=15
for i=1:size(array,2)
  if array(i)>threshold_for_noisy
    noisy_ind(i)=1;
  else
    noisy_ind(i)=0;
end
end

abnormal=zeros(1,size(array,2));
ch_pt=find(noisy_ind==1)

for i=1:2:size(ch_pt,2)-1
abnormal(ch_pt(i):ch_pt(i+1))=1
end
```

The elements in abnormal will be 1 whenever your signal exceeds the threshold and continues until it reaches back to normal (threshold_for_noisy).

Since the dataset you presented here doesn't have too much variance, simple comparison of past-future values as I suggested in my code will work. But if you have higher variance in your data, you can consider using a built-in function from Signal Processing Toolbox.

See [Matlab ischange function documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischange.html?lang=en)

Comment: This works but the problem is at when you look closer, lets say at 95,the value changes from 5 to 50 but at the 96th pixel till 100 the value is still around 50. How do you mark those points?

Comment: How about the revised version? You can shorten first part with another find function.

Comment: Wow the revised version works. Thanks a lot